# Unable to bind ObservableCollection to DataGrid in UserControl

Tags: uno-platform

I am trying to pass ObservableCollection from the XAML Page to the UserControl.

In a normal Visual Studio WPF project .NET Framework 4.8, within the UserControl the below XAML code works fine and the data can be seen within the Page.

`<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dgAuthors" ItemsSource="{Binding Authors, RelativeSource= RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:UserControl1}}`

Code behind of User Control as below:

```
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        dgAuthors.DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<Author>)GetValue(AuthorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AuthorsProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Authors.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AuthorsProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Authors", typeof(ObservableCollection<Author>), typeof(UserControl1), null);
```

But in UNO for .NET 5.0 framework, it is unable to find the `Mode=FindAncestor` and `AncestorType`  when Binding is used within the `ItemSource` of the DataGrid.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Many thanks

Neeraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the WinUI flavour of XAML used by Uno Platform, you can use [`x:Bind` syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) to bind to a property in code-behind:

```xml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dgAuthors" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Authors, Mode=OneWay}} />
```

Comment: Thanks @David for suggestion, but it doesn't seem to work. Have tried using Mode=TwoWay as well.

Comment: after trying various permutation combinations, it seems `x:Bind` is needed in the Page where the UserControl is consuming. Making the change in both the Page & UserControl with `x:bind`, the grid is getting populated.

*Page*
`<local:UserControl1 x:Name="uc1" MyText="{x:Bind Text, Mode=OneWay}" Authors="{x:Bind Authors, Mode=OneWay}"  Grid.Row="0" FontSize="45"/>`

*UserContol*
`<controls:DataGrid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="dgAuthors" ItemsSource="{x:Bind Authors, Mode=OneWay}" />`

Thanks for all your help!